# Create multiple objects using a single submit button with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my users to be able to invite multiple friends at once, using a single submit button. At first they are presented with one input field to enter an email with but they have the option to add more.

The user would fill in multiple fields and hit submit and the application will create the correct number of invites.

I can think of ways to do this with some jquery and ajax hackery but I was hoping someone out there knows of a more Rails way to do this. Using simple form for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select2-rails` gem. For more details visit [select2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails)

For example:

```
<%= f.label :user %>
<%= f.collection_select :user_ids, User.order(:name), :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'col-xs-12 col-md-7 padding_15', :multiple => true} %>

$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#product_category_ids').select2();
});
```